# Create Azure Table Storage

Tags: azure, storage

Can I check if my understanding is correct here.

To create an Azure Storage table I have to C# or Javacript, PHP etc.
There is no GUI for simply creating a table? And if there is a GUI, is it popular/recommended approach or a niche thing?

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is a **`Storage Explorer`**. There are many storage explorers available in the market today - There are both open source and commercial (both paid and free) storage explorers available. Please see this blog post from Windows Azure Storage Team about the list of storage explorers: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/04/17/windows-azure-storage-explorers.aspx.

Apart from these, `Visual Studio` also has a storage explorer built into it. You can find that in the `Server Explorer`. I haven't used Eclipse but I have heard that there's a storage explorer there as well.